# vb.net: How to Structure to IntPtr

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a vb6.0 (basic) project which I want to migrate to the new vs2022.
Most of the code just translated "more or less" fine, but there are some open points. I tried checking internet, but I couldnt find solution.
So here is my issue:

I have following code:

```
Public Structure Test
    Dim a as long
    Dim b as long
    ....
End structure

Public Sub xyz()
    'here im filling Test structure locally
    a = test... 
    ..

    A(a)
End sub
```

external dll function I want to call is `A([In] IntPtr Data)`

so the calling of A with my Test structure is failing, in vb6.0 it was working fine. I am not sure whats the problem. I tried some things, but I have no clue

I expected that it can just compile like its comiling in vb6.0. I have not touched any of this code part yet.

Another thing is that VarPtr() function is not available anymore. What could be the replacement in vs2022?

Comment: Unless you are calling an external COM based function, you will not need an `IntPtr`. Maybe there is a replacement in the .NET Library for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: yes you are right I am calling an external COM based function, sorry for not clearly stating it /showing it in my example code. I did a decompile on the COM function and the argument it requires is "[In] IntPtr Data"

Comment: You have to be much more specific, describe explicitly what you have to accomplish, the two languages are very different in this department -- You could use `Marshal.StructureToPtr()`, VarPtr could be replaced with a call to `CallWindowProc()` or `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem()`, but you should most probably replace the whole thing with .Net compatible code -- If you're dealing with old OCX stuff, something else is required etc.

Comment: Also the 32-bit VB6 `Long` corresponds to the VB.NET `Integer` and has a max value of 2,147,483,647. VB.NET `Long` is 64-bit with a max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. You will rarely need a `Long`. Is this COM based function a known Windows API? If yes, you may find .NET related info for it on the internet or you may find a VB method doing the same in the .NET Framework library.

Comment: @Jimi  Thx thats exactly what I needed. Sorry for being not detailed enough. You can answer and I can set to answered.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Ok thanks for the hint, I will adapt it accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what question I've answered. You should probably write the answer yourself, so you can explain what code you exactly have and what exactly you have changed to make it work

Comment: I just made a little WinForms .NET App to get an idea of the size of BCL (Base Class Library) with the standard references (you could add more). This is the result: # of assemblies = 85, # of public types = 4019, # of public properties = 21,330, # of public methods = 97,823. So, it is worth checking whether there is a .NET replacement for the required functionality before accessing external COM based functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to pass a structure to an unmanaged API as a pointer `Intptr`, I would do the following:

1. Allocate unmanaged memory of the size of the structure. `Dim buffer As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(T)))`
2. Pass the structure pointer to the unmanaged API.
3. When the unmanaged methods returns, converts the pointer to the structure using: `Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of T)(buffer)`
4. Do not forget to free the previously allocated unmanaged memory
   *`Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer)`*